# show/hide table data on the basis of selected checkbox in vue js and hide/show button

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I want to show/hide my table data. when I checked the checkboxes and on after a button click I want to hide them and vice versa.

I am able to put checkbox value to another inactiveList as an array but not able to bind to button.

this is my component file.....

```
<button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary"   v-on:click="seen(inactiveList)">hide/show</button>

  <table class="row-border hover">
    <tr>

               <th>Id</th>
                <th>Title</th>
                <th>UserId</th>
                <th>Change Detail</th>
                <th>Add Detail</th>

    </tr>

            <tr v-for = "(item,index) in paginate " :key= "index">
                <td>{{item.id}}</td>
                <td>{{item.title}}</td>
                <td>{{item.userId}}</td>
                <td><button class="btn btn-primary" >Edit</button></td>
                <td><button class="btn btn-primary" >Add</button></td>
                <td> <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle1"
                     v-on:change="list"  v-bind:value="item" v-model="inactiveList"><br></td>

    </tr>

</table>

 <ul>
    <li v-for="pageNumber in totalPages" v-if="Math.abs(pageNumber - currentPage) < 3
     || pageNumber == totalPages || pageNumber == 1">
    <a v-bind:key="pageNumber" href="#" @click="setPage(pageNumber)" 
    :class="{current: currentPage === pageNumber,
     last: (pageNumber == totalPages && Math.abs(pageNumber - currentPage) > 3),
     first:(pageNumber == 1 && Math.abs(pageNumber - currentPage) > 3)}">{{ pageNumber }}</a>
    </li>
</ul>

    </div>


  export default {
        name: 'component2',

        data(){

            return{

             currentPage: 1,
            itemsPerPage: 10,
            resultCount: 0,
            inactiveList:[],
            selected:false,

            }
        },
        computed: {

            ...mapState([

                'posts',
                'loading'
            ]),

           totalPages: function() {
          return Math.ceil(this.resultCount / this.itemsPerPage)
        },

           paginate: function() {
               debugger

            if (!this.posts || this.posts.length != this.posts.length) {
                return
            }
            this.resultCount = this.posts.length
            if (this.currentPage >= this.totalPages) {
              this.currentPage = this.totalPages
            }
            var index = this.currentPage * this.itemsPerPage - this.itemsPerPage
            return this.posts.slice(index, index + this.itemsPerPage)
        },

           },

        methods: {         

             setPage: function(pageNumber) {
          this.currentPage = pageNumber
        }, 

       list: function(){

         if(this.selected==false)
         {
          this.paginate.push= this.inactiveList;
           return  this.inactiveList
         }
       },

         seen: function(inactiveList){


        var index = this.inactiveList.length;

        for(var i=0;i<index;i++)
        {
          this.inactiveList[i].id;
          console.log(inactiveList[i].id)

        }

            },      
         },

        mounted() {
         this.$store.dispatch('loadPost');

        },


          }

</script>
```

this is my store.js file.....

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import axios from "axios";


Vue.use(Vuex,axios);

export const store = new Vuex.Store({

    state: {

        posts:[],
        loading: true

    },

    mutations:{       

    set_post(state,posts){

        state.posts=posts;
    },

    changeLoadingState(state, loading) {
        state.loading = loading
    }

},

   actions:{

   loadPost({commit})
   {
    axios
    .get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
    .then(response => {
      let post = response.data
      console.log(post)
      commit('set_post',post);
      commit('changeLoadingState', false)
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error)
      this.errored = true
    })
   },

}

  })
```

Comment: `paginate` is a function, not an object - so it definitely does not have a `push` method. What is the purpose of the statement `this.inactiveList[i].id;` in the `for` cycle in function `list` ?

Comment: I am getting the id of the inactive list

Comment: can u tell me the way of getting this as I am new to Vue js

Comment: You are not doing anything useful once you get the id. If you want to include/exclude an item from your array based on the click of a button - in the click handler you should do `itemsArray[index].flagVisible = ! itemsArray[index].flagVisible` and then provide the data table with the filtered result set, e.g. like `:items="itemsArray.filter(item => !!item.flagVisible)"

Comment: can you write code for click handler ???

Comment: I can, if you provide a CodePen or JSfiddle or similar snippet.

Comment: im not able to put store file there ??? can you do it as here

Comment: Okay, perhaps you can try with CodeSandbox ?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-5g4p8 check this

Comment: any idea of this

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-ojns6

Comment: thanks a lot, it works really nice...

Answer (score 0):

If I unterstood you correctly, you want to toggle visibility of each row and a possibility to unhide all hidden items.

To do that you should give each item a boolean flag if its currently visible or not.
You can store that in your data directly on each item as a property or make create an array based on index, if it's sorted data, or a map, if the sort of items happens to change anyway.

```
data() {
    return {
      useVisibility: false,
      items: {} // id -> item
    };
},
```

Don't forget to populate the map regarding this example code.

Now as you have provided the state you have to bind the inputs to each items boolean flag

```
<input type="checkbox" name="item.name"  @change="setVisibility(item.id, $event)" :value="item.visible" />
```

Provide a method to change the visibility flag

```
 setVisibility(id, event) {
    Vue.set(this.items, id, { ...this.items[id], visible: event.target.checked})
 }
```

Read up on the reactivity system if you don't know why I used Vue.set here. But maybe there is a better way to update the flag anyways.

To unhide all hidden items you just need to iterate over all items and set the visible flag to true with an v-on:click handler.

Write a computed property to get a list of visible items

```
computed: {
   visibleItems() {
      if (this.useVisibility) {
          // filter unchecked boxes
          return Object.values(this.items).filter(item => item.visible)
          // to filter checked boxes use the invert
          // return Object.values(this.items).filter(item => !item.visible)
      } else {
          return Object.values(this.items)
      }
   }
}
```

And render the list with a v-for. Notice. Use the id of the item so the VDOM can do its work properly.

```
<tr v-for="(item, index) in visibleItems" :key="item.id">
   ...
   <input type="checkbox" name="item.name"  @change="setVisibility(item.id, $event)" :checked="item.visible" />
</tr>
```

A button that hides/shows all checked items.

```
<button @click="useVisibility = !useVisibility"/>
```

See this [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Stejnar/uwd5pbh3/1/)

Comment: yeah but i want to show/hide them on a button click

Comment: I'm storing checked data to an empty array and then on button click, I want to hide that

Comment: I included the button hiding stuff.

Comment: return Object.values(this.items).filter(item => item.visible)
  what is object.values here ??

Comment: As this.items is a key/value map in this szenario and not an array, Object.values() grabs only the values aka items as an array.

Comment: I added a demo fiddle

Comment: how about hiding checked boxes row instead of unchecked rows.

Comment: just invert the condition for the filter function from filtering unchecked boxes to filter checked boxes.
before: `return Object.values(this.items).filter(item => item.visible)`
after: `return Object.values(this.items).filter(item => !item.visible)`

Comment: Did this solve your problem? Let me know if the answer needs improvements